# Import Data from Sales Force Report using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I am working on importing data from Salesforce Report using ADF. I am using copy activity and have created salesforce linked service.

I did get the below syntax from Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce.

Thanks to the documentation i can copy from SF report.

But there isn't a way to filter the report (eg filter 1 month of data). I just want to copy a small portion of it, not the whole report.

If anyone know how to do this let me know. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to copy the entire salesforce object?

Comment: Not yet. But I can preview the data. So I assume I can copy it.